# Join select in Laravel with

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have these two tables: properties and photos. 1 property can have 0 or N photos.

```
properties
|property_id|

photos
|photo_id|property_id|
```

Is there a way to fetch all the properties and their photos from DB as an array/object-like attribute using Eloquent?

Something like this:

```
$properties = [
[id => 1,
photos = [
    id => 101,
    id => 102]],
[id => 2,
photos = [
    id => 201,
    id => 202]],
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a `hasMany()` relationship in the `Property` model:

```
public function photos()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Photo::class, 'property_id', 'property_id');
}
```

Load the data and pass it to a view:

```
$properties = Property::with('photos')->get();
```

Display the data:

```
@foreach ($properties as $property)
    {{ $property->property_id }}
    @foreach ($property->photos as $photo)
        {{ $photo->photo_id }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Also, it's a good idea to [follow Laravel naming conventions](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions) described in my repo and rename `property_id` to `id` in the `properties` table. Then the relationship would look like:

```
public function photos()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Photo::class);
}
```

Comment: Excellent! This worked, thank you. Now I need to figure out how to optimize this query for 25.000 properties and 250.000 photos. Perhaps with LIMIT OFFSET.

Comment: @Eliel to limit properties use `take(1000)` for example. And I don't think you want to limit photos here.

Comment: @Eliel yes, you can use `offset()->limit()` or `skip()->take()`